# Diffusion - UNet - RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 1. Expected size 4 but got size 7 for tensor number 1 in the list

Tags: deep-learning, stable-diffusion, unet-neural-network

Newbee here:) I am trying to copying the course code from `How Diffusion Models Work` provided by **DeepLearning.AI**. The source code works on RGB images (if i remember correctly, size `[3,28,28]`) while I want to try it on classic `MNIST` dataset (grayscale image with size `[1,28,28]`).

So, I know that I need to modify the size of some `in_channels` and `out_channels` such that tensor dimension matches. However, I still get the tensor mismatch error message listing in the title.

Here is the original code to set up the `ContextUNet` which work for RBG images:

```
class ContextUnet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, n_feat=256, n_cfeat=10, height=28):  # cfeat - context features
        super(ContextUnet, self).__init__()

        # number of input channels, number of intermediate feature maps and number of classes
        self.in_channels = in_channels
        self.n_feat = n_feat
        self.n_cfeat = n_cfeat
        self.h = height  #assume h == w. must be divisible by 4, so 28,24,20,16...

        # Initialize the initial convolutional layer
        self.init_conv = ResidualConvBlock(in_channels, n_feat, is_res=True)

        # Initialize the down-sampling path of the U-Net with two levels
        self.down1 = UnetDown(n_feat, n_feat)        # down1 #[10, 256, 8, 8]
        self.down2 = UnetDown(n_feat, 2 * n_feat)    # down2 #[10, 256, 4,  4]
        
         # original: self.to_vec = nn.Sequential(nn.AvgPool2d(7), nn.GELU())
        self.to_vec = nn.Sequential(nn.AvgPool2d((4)), nn.GELU())

        # Embed the timestep and context labels with a one-layer fully connected neural network
        self.timeembed1 = EmbedFC(1, 2*n_feat)
        self.timeembed2 = EmbedFC(1, 1*n_feat)
        self.contextembed1 = EmbedFC(n_cfeat, 2*n_feat)
        self.contextembed2 = EmbedFC(n_cfeat, 1*n_feat)

        # Initialize the up-sampling path of the U-Net with three levels
        self.up0 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(2 * n_feat, 2 * n_feat, self.h//4, self.h//4), # up-sample 
            nn.GroupNorm(8, 2 * n_feat), # normalize                        
            nn.ReLU(),
        )
        self.up1 = UnetUp(4 * n_feat, n_feat)
        self.up2 = UnetUp(2 * n_feat, n_feat)

        # Initialize the final convolutional layers to map to the same number of channels as the input image
        self.out = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(2 * n_feat, n_feat, 3, 1, 1), # reduce number of feature maps   #in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride=1, padding=0
            nn.GroupNorm(8, n_feat), # normalize
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(n_feat, self.in_channels, 3, 1, 1), # map to same number of channels as input
        )

    def forward(self, x, t, c=None):
        """
        x : (batch, n_feat, h, w) : input image
        t : (batch, n_cfeat)      : time step
        c : (batch, n_classes)    : context label
        """
        # x is the input image, c is the context label, t is the timestep, context_mask says which samples to block the context on

        # pass the input image through the initial convolutional layer
        x = self.init_conv(x)
        # pass the result through the down-sampling path
        down1 = self.down1(x)       #[10, 256, 8, 8]
        down2 = self.down2(down1)   #[10, 256, 4, 4]
        
        # convert the feature maps to a vector and apply an activation
        hiddenvec = self.to_vec(down2)
        
        # mask out context if context_mask == 1
        if c is None:
            c = torch.zeros(x.shape[0], self.n_cfeat).to(x)
            
        # embed context and timestep
        cemb1 = self.contextembed1(c).view(-1, self.n_feat * 2, 1, 1)     # (batch, 2*n_feat, 1,1)
        temb1 = self.timeembed1(t).view(-1, self.n_feat * 2, 1, 1)
        cemb2 = self.contextembed2(c).view(-1, self.n_feat, 1, 1)
        temb2 = self.timeembed2(t).view(-1, self.n_feat, 1, 1)
        #print(f"uunet forward: cemb1 {cemb1.shape}. temb1 {temb1.shape}, cemb2 {cemb2.shape}. temb2 {temb2.shape}")


        up1 = self.up0(hiddenvec)
        up2 = self.up1(cemb1*up1 + temb1, down2)  # add and multiply embeddings
        up3 = self.up2(cemb2*up2 + temb2, down1)
        out = self.out(torch.cat((up3, x), 1))
        return out
```

So, in the final convolutional layers, i changed the `out_channel` of the last `nn.Conv2d` from `3` to `1` as follows:

```
# Initialize the final convolutional layers to map to the same number of channels as the input image
        self.out = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(2 * n_feat, n_feat, 3, 1, 1), # reduce number of feature maps   #in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride=1, padding=0
            nn.GroupNorm(8, n_feat), # normalize
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(n_feat, self.in_channels, 1, 1, 1), # map to same number of channels as input
        )
```

Then, I reset the model as:

`nn_model = ContextUnet(in_channels=1, n_feat=n_feat, n_cfeat=n_cfeat, height=height).to(device)  # for gray-scale in_channel=1`

However, it still gives me the similar error codes... I tried a few more very minor modifications in the last convolutional layers, the problem persists.

if you would like to take a look at the source codes and helper functions, here are the links:
[source codes and helper functions](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1W2-5sGEr-oslGgf6Z_KLQ6yukeskkgf8?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

OMG, it turns out that I do not need to modify the code for `ContextUNet`. I forgot to change the default image dimension from `16` to `28`...